# How to find only "new" messages when using PHP's IMAP functions for a POP3 mailbox?

Tags: php, email, imap, pop3

I'm using PHP's IMAP functions to retrieve messages from a POP3 mailbox & was wondering is there any way to tell the new messages apart from the old ones?

Unfortunately I cannot just delete the ones that are retrieved as they need to stay on the mail server, so I'm now wondering that each subsequent time I connect, how can I just retrieve the new ones OR be able to tell the new ones apart from the old ones I have already retrieved previously?

I know that each message has a UID attached to it & I could use this.. however I've read that this can change if the messages are deleted; as the messages may be deleted from the server down the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well found this..

> Basically, pop3 protocol doesn't support this function. However, you 
>   can implement this with message-id. Message-Id is an unique identifier of email on 
>   POP3 server. Your application can get message-id of a specified email by GetMsgID
>   method of POPMAIN object.
>
> Firstly, your application should record message-id of email retrieved to a local
>   message-id list. Next time before you retrieve email, compare local message-id 
>   with remote message-id. If this message-id exists in your
>   local message-id list, then it is old, otherwise it is new.

Although I'm pretty sure I read before that not all clients will returns the message_id... anyone know if this is correct?

Comment: Checking every messages id in the database will make your script run forever if you have thousands of messages in mailbox. Regarding message UID, some exchange server versions do not support that. I have yet to find a good way to fetch new messages..

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$result = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN');
```

Reference: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-unread-messages/