# PHP Displaying unread mail count

Tags: php, email, imap, pop3

I am using php imap class.
In my box I have a lot of mail, but with this script I would retrieve only the unreaded mail.
How can I do it?

```
if ($mbox=imap_open( "{" . $mailserver . ":" . $port . "}INBOX", $user, $pass )) 
{
  echo "Connected\n"; 
} else { exit ("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error() ."\n");  echo "FAIL!\n";  }; 

if ($hdr = imap_check($mbox)) {
  $msgCount = $hdr->Nmsgs;
  echo "Ci sono ".$msgCount." mail";
} else {
  echo "Failed to get mail";
}
```

If I do

```
$overview=imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:$msgCount",0);
```

the script load to an infinity time.

The imap_search UNSEEN solution is not good because pop3 don't use this flag.
So how can I do??????
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is the problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119402/how-to-find-only-new-messages-when-using-phps-imap-functions-for-a-pop3-mailbo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is two way you can follow:

**1. Looping through the messages**

```
$count = imap_num_msg($connection);
for($msgno = 1; $msgno <= $count; $msgno++) {

    $headers = imap_headerinfo($connection, $msgno);
    if($headers->Unseen == 'U') {
       ... do something ... 
    }

}
```

**2. Using imap_search**

There's a flag called UNSEEN which you can use to search for the unread emails. You would call the imap_search function with the UNSEEN flag like so:

```
$result = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN');
```

If you need to combine this with more search flags, for example searching for messages from me@example.com, you could do this:

```
$result = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN FROM "me@example.com"');
```

For a complete list of the available flags, refer to the criteria section of the imap_search manual page on the PHP website (www.php.net/imap_search)

Source: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-unread-messages/

Comment: But after imap_search how can I print the mails?

Comment: Because UNSEEN means UNREADED?

Answer (score 3):

This was a tough one on Google:   `php imap unread`

The first result:

- http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-unread-messages/

> There's a flag called UNSEEN which you can use to search for the unread emails. You would call the imap_search function with the UNSEEN flag like so:
>   view sourceprint?

```
 $result = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN');
```

> If you need to combine this with more search flags, for example searching for messages from me@example.com, you could do this:
>   view sourceprint?

```
 $result = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN FROM "me@example.com"');
```

> For a complete list of the available flags, refer to the criteria section of the imap_search manual page on the PHP website (www.php.net/imap_search)

**Edit** I had read this originally as IMAP.  #fail.

Google:  `php pop3 unread`

2nd link:

```
 function CountUnreadMails($host, $login, $passwd) {
      $mbox = imap_open("{{$host}/pop3:110}", $login, $passwd);
      $count = 0;
      if (!$mbox) {
           echo "Error";
      } else {
           $headers = imap_headers($mbox);
           foreach ($headers as $mail) {
                $flags = substr($mail, 0, 4);
                $isunr = (strpos($flags, "U") !== false);
                if ($isunr)
                $count++;
           }
      }

 imap_close($mbox);
 return $count;
 }
```

Comment: No it is no a good solution....the script is still loading and the result is: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: which solution?  1st?  2nd?  both?

Comment: Ok after $result = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN'); how can I print the mails?

Comment: this question is about unread count : )  if you need help with reading / printing the emails, select an answer here and open a new question ...