# Using IMAP () in PHP to get recent unread emails count

Tags: php, ubuntu, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to get no. of recent unread mails from a gmail account.For this I have installed IMAP in my Ubuntu system and tried some PHP iMAP functions.
Here are what i have tried till now.

```
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'user@gmail.com';
$password = 'user_password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' .    imap_last_error());
```

Now I am stating all my attempts.
NB - I have tried each attempt by sending new mails to the testing email id

Attempt_1: Using imap_search()

```
$recent_emails = imap_search($inbox,'RECENT');
if ($recent_emails)
   echo count($recent_emails);
else
   echo "false return";
imap_close($inbox);
```

Now Output of Attempt_1 is "false return";

Attempt_2: Using imap_mailboxmsginfo()

```
$check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($inbox);
if ($check)
    echo "Recent: "   . $check->Recent  . "<br />\n" ;
else
    echo "imap_check() failed: " . imap_last_error() . "<br />\n";
imap_close($inbox);
```

Here the output is Recent:0 while I have sent 2 new mails to this id

Attempt_3: using imap_status()

```
$status = imap_status($inbox, $hostname, SA_ALL);
if ($status)
  echo "Recent:     " . $status->recent      . "<br />\n";
else
  echo "imap_status failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
```

//Output Recent:0

Attempt_4: Using Using imap_search() Again with parameter NEW

```
$recent_emails = imap_search($inbox,'NEW');
if ($recent_emails)
   echo count($recent_emails);
else
   echo "false return";
imap_close($inbox);
```

Output - false return

So Where Am I WRONG?
How can I get the recent unread emails count?

Comment: Sorry it took so long for you to get an answer. They usually come much quicker. This is a well thought out and well formatted question. +1

Comment: Ya, I was waiting for the answer eagerly since I have post, and thanks for your remark on this, I need the solution badly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function seems to work:

```
function CountUnreadMail($host, $login, $passwd) {
    $mbox = imap_open($host, $login, $passwd);
    $count = 0;
    if (!$mbox) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        $headers = imap_headers($mbox);
        foreach ($headers as $mail) {
            $flags = substr($mail, 0, 4);
            $isunr = (strpos($flags, "U") !== false);
            if ($isunr)
            $count++;
        }
    }

    imap_close($mbox);
    return $count;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'user@gmail.com';
$password = 'user_password';

$count = CountUnreadMail($hostname, $username, $password);
```

I can’t claim full credit for this function. It’s a slightly edited version of sdolgy’s answer to [PHP Displaying unread mail count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6707581/911182). His version assumed POP mail. This version requires the full `$hostname`. I tested it with my own gmail account and it correctly reported the number of *unread* messages I had in my inbox.

[PHP Displaying unread mail count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6707581/911182) has some pretty good reading material. Check it out.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

From: [Does Gmail support all IMAP features?](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78761)

> Gmail IMAP1 is a fairly complete implementation of IMAP, but the
>   following features are currently unsupported:
>
> ```
> \Recent flags on messages.
> ```

Verfied at: [Gmail's Buggy IMAP Implementation](http://weblog.timaltman.com/archive/2008/02/24/gmails-buggy-imap-implementation)

> Gmail doesn't handle standard IMAP flags, such as "\Deleted",
>   "\Answered", and "\Recent".

**See also:** [Jyoti Ranjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7441374/911182) (below) for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks Herbert for your reply, I was asking to get no. of RECENT Unread mails, means the no. of new mails after last log in. I think your code will give the no. of UNREAD mails, but i will try this code surely and let you know.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. I just had a friend send me an email and used `var_dump` on the `$headers` variable to see what came up. Unfortunately, the only flag sent is U (unread). There's nothing to indicate if it's recent. I also used `imap_status` as you did and UNSEEN is set, but not RECENT.

Comment: Apparently, it's not possible with gmail. See my update in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info Herbert, at least I am not in the dark now, will try some other method to get my work done

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. I didn't mean that you had to accept _mine_. You can also post your own answer and accept that. Nevertheless, I appreciate it and I'm glad you were able to solve the problem. :)

Comment: I accepted your post as Answer because it has lots of info and perhaps I wont be able to think the solution in my way if I don't get the gmail bugs info. So when someone will read this question,he will read urs first and came to know about gmail bug, then he may see my solution in my environment or can think something else to solve his problem, So Info is more imp. than solution as solution can be many :)

Comment: @Jyoti: Well said. I never considered that. :)

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it using database,This is how I have done it.

1.I made a column in users table, for ex- 'email_max_uid' INT(11) NOT NULL default 0

2.When a user loads this page first, using my sql query I retrieved the value of 'email_max_uid' of that particular users
3.connect to his gmail account automatically and got the unread mails and total mails

```
$inbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX','user's email id','user's password') or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
        $unread_emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
        $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL', SE_UID);
```

4.Then

```
if ('email_max_uid') = 0
        $recent_mails_count = count($unread_emails);
    else
        $recent_mails_count = max($emails) - Array['email_max_uid'];
```

5.Show the recent mails count

```
echo count($recent_mails_count);
```

6.I have put a link which makes the user log in to his gmail account without asking his email id and password
When the users log in to his account, `email_max_uid is updated with count($emails)`

1. Now again when the users visits that page, it follows the above proceedure and his no. of recent emails will be displayed on the page.

*My solution is for the case where a user can log in to his gmail account only through this application, if he logs into his account from outside, the database wont be updated so that wrong no. of mail counts will be shown.In my problem case, user even doesn't know his gmail id and password provided by the company to see only their mails. So he cant log in to his this account from outside. That's why this solution works.

This is how I solved it 3 days ago.Sorry for late reply

Comment: +1 I'm glad you solved it. Something like this could come in handy (considering GMail's shortcomings).

Comment: Ya, I just used the basic concepts of PHP and solved it according to my requirement. Hope gmail will remove its bug so that more IMAP () will be used.