# Get imap unread email count in .net without bloated 3rd party libs

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, imap

**Background:** 
We have an internal intranet system written in [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic) and [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) - the [iis](/questions/tagged/iis) server doesnt have [php](/questions/tagged/php) installed (Seen some nifty solutions in php such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363077/using-imap-in-php-to-get-recent-unread-emails-count) but we cant really use these.) - we need to display to our users how many unread email they have in their imap mailbox. Their imap mailbox is hosted internally on a linux box running postfix and dovecot imap.

**My Question:**
How would one connect to Postfix mail system via Dovecot Imap in .net (vb or c#) and determine the number of unread items?

**What I've already tried:**
We used the [Limilabs mail dll](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) and the following:

```
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System
Imports Limilabs.Mail
Imports Limilabs.Client.IMAP
Imports Limilabs.Client

Function RetrieveUnread(_server, _user, _password)
    Using imap As New Limilabs.Client.IMAP.Imap
        '#### Handler needed because of self signed certificates
        RetrieveUnread = vbNull
        AddHandler imap.ServerCertificateValidate, AddressOf ValidateCertificate
        imap.ConnectSSL(_server)
        Try
            imap.Login(_user, _password)
        Catch ex As Exception
            RetrieveUnread = "Failed to login"
        End Try
        If CStr(RetrieveUnread) <> "Failed to login" Then
            imap.SelectInbox()
            Dim uids As List(Of Long) = imap.Search(Flag.Unseen)        'Find all unseen messages.
            'Console.WriteLine("Number of unseen messages is: " & CStr(uids.Count))
            RetrieveUnread = CStr(uids.Count)
        End If
        imap.Close()
    End Using
End Function

Private Sub ValidateCertificate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ServerCertificateValidateEventArgs)
    Const ignoredErrors As SslPolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors Or SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch        ' name mismatch
    Dim nameOnCertificate As String = e.Certificate.Subject
    If (e.SslPolicyErrors And Not ignoredErrors) = SslPolicyErrors.None Then
        e.IsValid = True
        Return
    End If
    e.IsValid = False
End Sub
```

However, whilst this works, this method is subject to reliance on a 3rd party, DLL will fail if licencing is not in place / up to date & is heavily bloated for what we need to do. We where just curious if this can be done in native .net code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a 3rd party dll; a simple [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) will do.

You can just send the right IMAP commands to your server, and parse the result with a regular expression.

---

**LINQPad-ready example:**

```
Sub Main()
    Dim client = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("hostname", 143)
    Using s = client.GetStream(), 
        reader = New StreamReader(s),
        writer = New StreamWriter(s)

            Dim send As Action(Of String) = Sub(command) 
                writer.WriteLine(command)
                writer.Flush()
            End Sub

            Dim recieve As Func(Of String, String) = Function(tag) 
                Dim response As String
                Dim str As String = ""
                response = reader.ReadLine()
                While response IsNot Nothing
                    str += response
                    If response.StartsWith(tag, StringComparison.Ordinal) Then
                        Exit While
                    End If
                    response = reader.ReadLine()
                End While
                Return str
            End Function

            send("a login username password"): recieve("a")
            send("b select inbox"): recieve("b")

            send("b2 SEARCH UNSEEN")
            Dim b2response = recieve("b2")
            Dim items = Regex.Match(b2response, "SEARCH (.*) OK").Groups(1).Value.Split(" "c)
            Console.WriteLine("Unread items: " + items.Count().ToString())

            send("c logout"): recieve("c")
    End Using
End Sub
```

---

```
void Main()
{
    var client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("hostname", 143);
    using (var s = client.GetStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(s))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(s))
    {
        Action<string> send = (command) => 
        {
            writer.WriteLine(command);
            writer.Flush();
        };

        Func<String, String> recieve = (tag) =>
        {
            string response;
            string str="";
            while ((response = reader.ReadLine()) != null ) 
            {
                str+=response;
                if (response.StartsWith(tag, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    break;
            }
            return str;
        };

        send("a login username password"); recieve("a");
        send("b select inbox"); recieve("b");

        send("b2 SEARCH UNSEEN");
        var b2response = recieve("b2");
        var items = Regex.Match(b2response, @"SEARCH (.*) OK").Groups[1].Value.Split(' ');
        Console.WriteLine("Unread items: " + items.Count().ToString());

        send("c logout"); recieve("c");
    }
}
```

If you want to use SSL, you have to wrap the stream `s` in an [`SslStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) and call [`AuthenticateAsClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145060.aspx) first (and probably use port 993).

Comment: ``RECENT`` may not be particularly useful, especially if their mail is being accessed by other connections.  You could do a ``SEARCH UNREAD``, and count the responses, which might be closer to what the OP wants.

Comment: @Max I think it's `SEARCH UNSEEN` instead of `SEARCH UNREAD`. Otherwise, you're right.

Comment: I don't remember if I gave you the downvote or not;  However, I wouldn't recommend the OP write an IMAP client from scratch.  There's a lot of subtleties in the protocol.  It may be sufficient for just getting a count, but would be very hard to do much more than that.

Comment: @Max The OP explicitly asked how to determine the number of unread items, without a 3rd party library.

Comment: We decided to go the PHP route for this - was MUCH easier. Marking your post as answer anyway as the logic looks sound – don’t see why it’s been downvoted :S

Comment: I checked my history, and it wasn't my downvote, I don't think.  Anyways, yes, he did ask without using a 3rd party library.  But I think, in the end, he would have more trouble trying to implement it himself.  He decided to go with PHP anyways. :)

Comment: Your answer is a good starting point for a rudimentary IMAP client. Since `STARTTLS` requires additional work, I guess most people will sooner rather than later use (open source) 3rd party libs anyway. However, you earned an upvote.