# PHP - imap count unseen emails gives always '1' as result

Tags: php, html, email, count, imap

Trying to count the unseen emails in my email box, the script I have does the counting however, when there are no unseen emails the result is always 1 and no 0. Any idea why?

here the code I have so far.

php:

```
    $hostname = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = 'myemail@example.co.uk';
    $password = 'mypass';
    $imap = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die("imap connection error");
    $result = imap_search($imap, 'UNSEEN');
    $new_inbox_msg = count($result);
    echo $new_inbox_msg
```

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump()`ing `$result`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707581/php-displaying-unread-mail-count

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363077/using-imap-in-php-to-get-recent-unread-emails-count

Try these threads, I hope they help in some way!

Comment: You should always transparentyl mark the changes to the question you make, if they are non-trivial. Otherwise things get _very_ confusion...

Comment: thank @JonStirling adding var_dump is resulting as int(1)

Comment: @SNos No it doesn't. First you edited your question so the context of the code completely changed, and now you're giving different answers in the comments of you question and comments on arkascha's answer. Please sort yourself out and make sure what you're telling us is accurate and consistent with the code provided.

Comment: yes var_dump results int(number)

Comment: Your own comment on the answer. `result contains an array –  SNos`.

Comment: yes $result and not var_dump($result)

Comment: ... if `$result` is an array, then the `var_dump()` would have shown an array, not just an int. Whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imap_search()` returns an *array*, not a number, according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php).

So instead you need:

```
$result = imap_search($imap, 'UNSEEN');
echo count($result);
```

---

OK, sorry, miss interpreted the documentation myself. So here an explanation of your issue: the function indeed does return an array, *but* an array holding one result (count) per search attribute you handed over. Since you only specify a single attribute ('UNSEEN') you *always* get a single element in the array. *That* elements value is the number of messages matching that search criteria.

Therefore the correct usage should be:

```
$result = imap_search($imap, 'UNSEEN');
if (is_array($result) && isset($result[0])) {
    echo count($result[0]);
} else {
    echo "Failed to query number of messages\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you tried this but if there are no unseen emails the result shows 1

Comment: @SNos So what does `$result` contain in that case?

Comment: for example if I have 5 unread emails the result is '5' however, if none the results shows '1'. If 1 unseen emails result is '1'

Comment: @SNos Once more: _what_ does `$result` contain in that case? You see, you have to tell us, we cannot see what your imap account returns... So if you want to find the issue here you have to dump the variable.

Comment: result contains an array

Comment: @SNos And what is the content of that array in that case?

Comment: if one unseen email and 6 seen the content is Array ( [0] => 6 ). If 0 print_r does not show anything

Comment: thank you this help me a lot, and sorry for the edit, while i was writing the question I forgot to add the count part

Comment: I made another change to the answer, please take a look at it again. I have to apologize: initially I miss understood the documentation myself (didn't read enough...). The above code lines should now be the correct approach...

Comment: Thank you so much @arkascha still need to understand how to search inside arrays