# Php reading email from pop

Tags: php, email, pop3

this is my code:

```
  if ($mbox=imap_open( "{" . $mailserver . ":" . $port . "}INBOX", $user, $pass )) 
 {  echo "Connected\n"; 
 } else { exit ("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error() ."\n");  echo "FAIL!\n";  }; 

 if ($hdr = imap_check($mbox)) {
  $msgCount = $hdr->Nmsgs;
  echo "Ci sono ".$msgCount." mail";
} else {
  echo "Failed to get mail";

}

$connection=$mbox;
$result = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN');
  $output='';

 foreach($result as $email_number) {

    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$email_number,2);

    /* output the email header information */
    $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
    $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
    $output.= '</div>';

    /* output the email body */
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
  }

  echo $output;

imap_close($mbox);
```

The problem is that the script is too low and I have returned Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.

How can I do?
In my mailbox I have much mail (20 unread).

The problem is that when I do imap_search UNSEEN it return me all the mail, also the read mail. 
So UNSEEN option don't work.
The mailbox is yahoo and in my box I have 990 mails and 1 unread.
The problem is that it return me that 990 are unreaded but it is not true...only 1 is unreaded!

What may be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: This is the problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119402/how-to-find-only-new-messages-when-using-phps-imap-functions-for-a-pop3-mailbo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the [max_execution](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) time in PHP, however you should try to profile what makes your application so slow.

Does the error message give you any aditional hints, or do you know if the IMAP server is slow?

Comment: The problem is that when I do imap_search UNSEEN it return me all the mail, also the read mail. So UNSEEN option don't work. The mailbox is yahoo. So in my box I have 990 mails and 1 unread. The problem is that it return me that 990 are unreaded but it is not true... What's the problem

Comment: Your problem isnt the max execution time, but it just doesnt mark unread messages properly?

Comment: Yes, if I go on Yahoo mail on www.yahoo.com I have 1 unread mail on 990mail. The script return me that all the mail are unreaded.