# Zend Mail Pop3 Reading only unread message

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, pop3

I would ask you if exist a possibility for retrieve only unreaded message via pop3.

Imap has UNSEEN flag so it can be done with some library.

But if I have only pop3? How can I retrieve only the un readed mails?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Displaying unread mail count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707581/php-displaying-unread-mail-count) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707950/php-reading-email-from-pop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POP3 does not support unread flag. Imap does :-) You can use the Zend Framework to handle this with imap.

I have done this to find "bounced" mails:

```
$subjectIfFailed = 'Delivery Status Notification (Failure)';
$bouncedMails = array();

$params = array(
    'user'     => $config->gmail->user,
    'host'     => $config->gmail->host,
    'password' => $config->gmail->password,
    'port'     => $config->gmail->port,
    'ssl'      => (bool) $config->gmail->ssl, 
);

$mailStorage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($params);

$count = $mailStorage->count();
$i = 1;

while ($i <= $count) {
    $message = $mailStorage->getMessage($i);

    if ($message->hasFlag(Zend_Mail_Storage::FLAG_SEEN) === false) {

        if (strtolower($message->getHeader('subject')) == 
            strtolower($subjectIfFailed)) {
                  $bouncedMails[] = $message->getHeader('x-failed-recipients');
        }           
    }
    $i++;
}

return $bouncedMails;
```

Comment: But if I have only pop3? How can I retrieve only the un readed mails?

Answer (score 1):

A POP3 server - by default - deletes the message from the server once taken. So the messages that have been read (taken) do not exist any longer. You need to specify an option that they stay on the server per the connection. I don't know [`Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3` <sup>**API Docs**</sup>](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Mail/Storage/Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3.html) that well to tell you what the flag/option is, but there should be one. [Check the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html).

**Edit:** Just scanning the docs. It might be that no such flag exists for the POP3 implementation in *Zend Framework*. Probably you can connect via IMAP (I fear not because you write about IMAP already in your question) or alternatively - but that would mean you switch away from the Zend library - you can implement that on your own with the [PHP imap library <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) that does handle pop3 as well and offers such a flag.

Comment: Do you know another library that allow it? Thanks.

Comment: I have tried imap library but the flag for unreaded mail is relative for imap and it don't work for pop3. It return a non correct number of unreaded mails.

Comment: I readhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119402/how-to-find-only-new-messages-when-using-phps-imap-functions-for-a-pop3-mailbo . I think that it is the unique possibility.

Comment: Maybe you can store the mails you've already taken on your server, for example in a database or in the file-system. Zend offers the `Maildir` storage for that. It even supports flags. You can copy mails over and keep your local store like a mailclient. That's maybe the sweetest thing to work around. Both are `Zend_Mail_Storage`s, so should be relatively easy.